# Accessing Remote Network Share

Tags: windows, network-shares, remote

I have a computer in one of our remote locations.  It running Windows 7 Pro and I need to access one of the mapped drives remotely.  The trouble I have is that it is doing something a little strange in that I cannot access via remote desktop and the only way in appears to be `\\[ip address]\c$`.

Trouble is I need the `p:` share.

Is there a way to map this (p:) remotely so I can access this via the ip address, like I can with the c: drive?

I can access the manage tool and can connect to the other computer, but I cannot see whether this would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the "Manage Computer" tool, and connect to the remote machine with it, you should be able to open the "Shared Folders" folder and create the share there.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, i'll give it a go tomorrow when I'm back in the office :)

Comment: Unfortunately mapped drives do not show here. I've tried on a fully functioning computer for comparison and I cannot see any network mapped drives there either....

Comment: Well, no.  Network-mapped drives cannot be shared.  Simply connect to the share directly from your client machine.  Sorry, I  misunderstood your question originally.